# Heroku Deploy Failing but Local Build and Compile Succeed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, bower

Angular app using node, bower and gulp.

**Problem**
When trying to log in on Heroku: TypeError: w is not a function

Initial builds in local environment were fine. Gulp build and was able to login. Gulp compile and was able to login on local IIS. Deploy to Heroku and get the above error. Cannot replicate locally even after going back to last known good commit on Heroku.

Delete local version of project and rebuild. Can now replicate the error in local environment. Find solution on SO re same angular-resource method and same angular-resource version. Angular was version 1.5.9, angular-resource was 1.6.1. Rebuild with angular-resource as 1.5.9 and all is good. I can now login without error locally: build and compile to local IIS without error.

Updated bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "Removed",
  "authors": [
    "Removed"
  ],
  "description": "Removed",
  "main": "index",
  "moduleType": [],
  "keywords": [
    "Removed"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://Removed",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.9",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.9",
    "angular-touch": "1.5.9",
    "angular-messages": "1.5.9",
    "angular-toastr": "^1.7.0",
    "angular-ui-tree": "^2.16.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
    "angular-auto-validate": "^1.19.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "angular-snap": "^1.8.5",
    "angular-localforage": "^1.2.5",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "angular-busy": "^4.1.3",
    "aws-sdk": "aws-sdk-js#^2.6.11",
    "ng-csv": "^0.3.6",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.9",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.9"
  }
}
```

And package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Removed",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Removed",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.6.0",
    "npm": "3.6.0"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower cache clean && bower install && npm run build-all",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build-all": "gulp inject index",
    "test": "gulp test:unit",
    "test-e2e": "gulp test:e2e"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Removed"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Removed"
  ],
  "author": "Removed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://Removed/"
  },
  "homepage": "https://Removed/",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "1.7.7",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-beautify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-csso": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp-less-import": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-ng-constant": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "gulp-open": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-wrapper": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-node": "^1.14.5",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.11.1",
    "plato": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "^3.1.1",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "selenium-standalone": "^4.9.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.52.0",
    "yargs": "^3.32.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

The problem still persists on Heroku even with the cache clean, and the dependencies matching. The build log is clean and reads that there were no issues. **What am I missing for this to work on Heroku?**

Heroku log with minor items redacted

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  5.6.0
   engines.npm (package.json):   3.6.0

   Downloading and installing node 5.6.0...
   npm 3.6.0 already installed with node
-----> Restoring cache
   Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (package.json):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components
-----> Building dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json)

   > **removed**-seed@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_f9f5334ca3b4f65239fd45fcbf9493ea/**removed**-959eff2
   > bower cache clean && bower install && npm run build-all


   > **removed**-seed@1.0.0 build-all /tmp/build_f9f5334ca3b4f65239fd45fcbf9493ea/**removed**-959eff2
   > gulp inject index

   [18:43:00] Using gulpfile /tmp/build_f9f5334ca3b4f65239fd45fcbf9493ea/**removed**/gulpfile.js
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:inject'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:scripts'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:assets'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:app-config'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:bower-fonts'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:styles'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean-index'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:app-js'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:lib-js'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:app-css'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:fonts'...
   [18:43:00] Starting 'clean:images'...
   [18:43:00] Finished 'clean:inject' after 24 ms
   [18:43:00] Finished 'clean:scripts' after 18 ms
   [18:43:00] Starting 'scripts'...
   [18:43:00] Finished 'clean:app-config' after 50 ms
   [18:43:00] Starting 'app-config'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:styles' after 55 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'styles'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:assets' after 109 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'assets'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:bower-fonts' after 111 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'bower-fonts'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean-index' after 115 ms
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:app-css' after 112 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'app-css'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:app-js' after 155 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'app-js'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:lib-js' after 171 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'lib-js'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:fonts' after 211 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'fonts'...
   [18:43:01] Finished 'clean:images' after 215 ms
   [18:43:01] Starting 'images'...
   [18:43:11] Finished 'app-config' after 11 s
   [18:43:19] gulp-imagemin: Minified 14 images (saved 44.42 kB - 5.5%)
   [18:43:33] Finished 'bower-fonts' after 33 s
   [18:43:35] Finished 'lib-js' after 35 s
   [18:43:35] Finished 'assets' after 35 s
   [18:43:35] Finished 'images' after 35 s
   [18:43:36] Finished 'fonts' after 35 s
   [18:43:39] Finished 'styles' after 38 s
   [18:43:42] Finished 'app-css' after 42 s
   [18:43:42] Finished 'scripts' after 42 s
   [18:43:42] Starting 'inject'...
   [18:43:42] gulp-inject 30 files into index.html.
   [18:43:42] gulp-inject 49 files into index.html.
   [18:43:42] Finished 'inject' after 213 ms
   [18:43:46] Finished 'app-js' after 46 s
   [18:43:46] Starting 'index'...
   [18:43:46] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
   [18:43:46] gulp-inject 2 files into index.html.
   [18:43:46] Finished 'index' after 27 ms
-----> Caching build
   Clearing previous node cache
   Saving 2 cacheDirectories (package.json):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> (none)
   Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 53M
-----> Launching...
   Released v89
   **removed** deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: what `engines` do you use for your app?

Comment: @orvi WebStorm is the dev tool, and I am using node, bower and gulp. IIS is for my local deployment before passing to live, which is also IIS.

Comment: No no .Did you add the `engines` in your `package.json` file ?

Comment: @orvi: Yes! Sorryfor the confusion:"engines": {
    "node": "5.6.0",
    "npm": "3.6.0"
  },

Comment: can you share the full code of `package.json` file with the fquestion?

Comment: @orvi Hello. The complete bower and package json files are added to the original.

Comment: can you add the log file too ? You may find it in your dashboard.

Comment: Do you have the procfile ?, how are you saying which port are you using to heroku??

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval I do not have a procfile specified on Heroku or in my git repo. It is just going to default port to my knowledge. On the Heroku site I go to my deploy tab, point to a git repo, pick a branch, and let Heroku do its thing. The error is still the same as before I updated angular-resource. Its like it is not recognizing the package.

Comment: Yeah, but you always need to use a profile to tell your app what port is Heroku  using, maybe the port default is not free and is trying to giving you another

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval: Thank you. I'll rtfm and see what I can come up with. I've been running this code on Heroku for months without issue. This whole situation popping up now is just odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to package dependencies. The bower.json file was updated.

Angular was set to ^1.6.1 and the other angular packages to ^1.5.9